# Relative path within TZipFile

Tags: c++builder

I am trying to convert some code that used `TZipForge` for years to code that uses `TZipFile` in the RTL now. My reason is so that I can exchange files between VCL app and FMX mobile apps. I am using C++ Builder 11.2.1 for all of these apps.

The structure in the Zip file that I am struggling with is like:

```
folder-1\
-- file-1.xml
-- file-2.xml
file-a.xml
file-b.xml
```

I find that I can insert `file-a` & `file-b` *without* path info. I can't insert `folder-1\file-1` and `folder-1\file-2` because `folder-1` is a relative path within the Zip file. It is not a complete path on the file system. Also, I am using `IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter()` so that these are OS independent path separators.

If I do this:

```cpp
Zip->Add("file-1", "folder-1\\file-1");
```

I get a "file not found" error because `folder-1\\file-1` does not exist on the file system.

Is it possible to create a **relative** path (folder) within a zip file and add files to that folder?

Comment: the second parameter is the path of the file *inside* the zip, so it should not be causing filesystem errors. Only the 1st parameter is used on the filesystem. Do you have the same problem if you open the file with a `TFileStream` and then pass that as the 1st parameter? Have you tried using `folder-1/file-1` yet (ie, change the backslash into a forward-slash)?

Comment: Same problem with TFileStream. Also, I changed the separator in the 2d parameter to folder-1/file-1.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you then. "file not found" is not an error that `TZipFile.Add()` throws for the `ArchiveFileName` parameter. I suggest you turn on the "Use debug dcus" option in your project and step through `TZipFile`'s source code with the debugger to see what is really going on.

Comment: I'm using C++ so I don't think that works for me. Nonetheless, I am going to try a little more. Thank you so much for responding!

Comment: Debugging Embarcadero's source code works the same in C++Builder as it does in Delphi. Besides, all of the frameworks you use outside of the standard C++ library, including TZipFile, are written in Delphi anyway.

Comment: You're so right! Sorry for the mental fumble. I'm working on it now...
- Phyllis

Comment: Remy, your statement about the parameters to Open() reassured me that I should examine those. With the debugger I found that the first parameter had to include the full path, unlike the TZipForge version. This solved the initial problem but ultimately I had to revert to using TZipForge. I'm sure I will revisit this...